# iOS app release - same Bundle ID but different Developer accounts

Tags: ios, release

I have created an app for which a different version was created earlier. The older app had a different Bundle ID from mine, but it has the name I want to use. So if I want to release the app with the same name:

1) Do I have to use the same Bundle ID?

2) Does it matter if the app is being submitted using a different developer account?

3) What about the App ID?

Comment: The bundle ID is the unique identifier of your app. If you use a new bundle ID for your new app (or new version of your app), the new app will have nothing to do with the old app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your goal? If you want the same name, then your only option is to use a different bundle ID and see if your app name is available in a different locale within iTunes connect.

Your bundle ID has to be different. But the bundle ID has no intrinsic connection to the app name. However, again, within iTunes connect, your app name within locales has to be different.

Comment: What do you mean by a locale? Is it a geographic distinction? Or based on target devices?

Comment: Example EN (US) vs. EN (UK). When you create an app in iTunes connect, one of the options is locale. Keep in mind if you select some obscure locale, iTunes expects your description of the app to be in that locale (language).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your app will be rejected if you try to use the same name and/or same Bundle ID. The point of that is that it uniquely identifies your application

If you want to replace the older app, you will need to use the older developer account and submit an update

Comment: I see. Is there no way delete the older app?

Comment: Do you control the old app? You can delete the old app if you control it. Keep in mind the name may not be released for up to 4 months for a new app.